# USBRequest returning on UI Thread?

Tags: android, usb

I am writing an Android app that communicates with a USB device in OTG mode, so the phone is the master and the device is the slave. I have read through the Android USB Communication documentation and looked at several examples online. With the below code, I want to send a buffer to my USB device and await a response from it.

```
doAsync {
    val request = UsbRequest()
    request.initialize(usbConnection, usbReadEndpoint)

    request.queue(byteBuffer)

    if (usbConnection?.requestWait() === request) {
        SOME CODE WITH BREAKPOINTS
    }
}
```

When I debug this, I set a breakpoint inside the if clause to see when the response for the request has arrived. When I execute this code, the breakpoint is never hit immediately and does not arrive unless I do something *extra*.

By extra, I mean the following. There is a RecyclerView in the activity where I run this code. It contains an item. When I physically click it, the breakpoint inside the if clause is hit. If I don't, nothing will happen. Also, pressing the back button to relaunch the activity causes the breakpoint in the if clause to be hit. What's interesting is that this breakpoint is hit even before any other code in the activity is executed (I know this because I set other breakpoints as well).

My question is - Why does this happen? Why does my request only arrive once I do something on the UI or restart the activity? Is this really what's happening or am I missing something here? How do I make a "healthy" requestWait() to receive data when I want it?